# Whats the impact of fit_transform in machine learning

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

We usually apply `.fit_transform()` on `X_train` and `.transform()` on `X_test`

This is because they are from the same dataset. What if we apply `fit_transform()` to the `X_test` again. How will this affect our model?

Comment: These are methods that most sklearn transformers have, *not the models*. How will it affect? It totally depends on the kind of features, and transformation applied

Comment: Related question: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/whats-the-difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, if you're applying a `SimpleImputer` to impute numeric missing values with the mean, each time you call the `fit_transform` method you are:

- calculating the mean for that variable(s)
- substituting the missing with the calculated mean

Now, if you apply `fit_transform` to both train and test, it could give 2 different mean for each variable, thus resulting in 2 different data processes.

Moreover, here's another less statistical, more practical issue. If you deploy the process in production and apply this process to a single record, which "mean" will you use? The train one or the test one? Or would you apply `fit_transform` also to that record, calculating the mean of one?